# How to configure cumulusci in Robot Framework?

Tags: salesforce, robotframework

I am working on a proof-of-concept at my organization to use robot framework along with seleniumlibrary and cumulusci for automating our salesforce based platform. Here is what i have setup so far:

1. I have added the cumulusci resource in my .robot project file such as this:
   import resource  ${CURDIR}/cumulusci/robotframework/Salesforce.robot at Suite Setup level
2. I have also placed my .robot project file at this location:
   ${CURDIR}/cumulusci/tests/MyProjectFile.robot
3. My ${CURDIR} as well cumulusci location is in the windows system PATH variable.

Note: At this moment, I am able to identify and click elements on Ui purely based on seleniumlibrary, however i also need to be able to leverage cci capabilities.

When I try to use:

```
*** Test Cases ***
TestSample
Salesforce.Click Object Button  <mybuttonstitle>
```

I get:
No keyword with name 'Salesforce.Click Modal Button' found.

my references:
https://cumulusci.readthedocs.io/en/latest/robotframework.html
https://cumulusci.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_downloads/Keywords.html

Looking for help related to cci setup, accessing keywords or any other aspect you guys feel I am missing on cci-rfw front.

Thanks.

Comment: Is this your actual test case, exactly as presented in the question? If so, it should give a completely different error than the one you report. Please make sure that your [mcve] actually causes the error you're reporting.

Comment: is this still a problem? Can you please update your question with more information, or close the question if you no longer need help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your help Bryan and KJ. The actual issue was of incorrect folder structure that I created. When I sorted that out, my cumulusci keywords started working. This is what I referred: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/robotframework-users/iaeUZU_htk4

#### CommonEnvironment.robot

```
*** Keywords ***

Call all python libraries and resources
    import library  SeleniumLibrary  timeout=20
    import library  OperatingSystem
    import resource  C:/Python37/Lib/site-packages/cumulusci/robotframework/Keywords/CommonKeywords.robot
    import resource  C:/Python37/Lib/site-packages/cumulusci/robotframework/Salesforce.robot
    import resource  C:/Python37/Lib/site-packages/cumulusci/robotframework/CommonVariables.robot
```

#### MyAppTestCases.robot

```
*** Settings ***

Resource  C:/Python37/Lib/site-packages/cumulusci/robotframework/CommonEnvironment.robot

Suite Setup  Call all python libraries and resources
Test Setup  Setup Browser
Test Teardown  End Session

*** Test Cases ***

Verify so and so

    Login to Salesforce
    Launch My App
```

#### CommonKeywords.robot

```
*** Keywords ***

Login to Salesforce

    Wait Until Page Contains Element  ${signOn_username}
    Input Text  ${signOn_username}  ${Username}
    Wait Until Page Contains Element  ${signOn_password}
    Input Text  ${signOn_password}  ${Password}
    Click Element  ${loginButton}

    ${Pass}=  RUN KEYWORD AND RETURN STATUS  Wait Until Page Contains Element'  ${MostRecentlyViewed}

    run keyword if  '${Pass}'=='True'  Log  "SF Home page loaded successfully"
    ...  ELSE  Fail  "SF Home page did not load successfully"

Launch My App

    Open App Launcher   # this is the cumulusci keyword - and it works well now!
    Select App Launcher App  MyApp
    ...
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe, you are missing the import of the `Salesforce` library,

```
*** Settings ***
Resource        cumulusci/robotframework/Salesforce.robot
```

Also, please ensure if necessary Python package have been installed already.